# jQuery slideUp and slideDown as page transitions

Tags: jquery, function, slidedown, preventdefault, slideup

I would like to make my website to do some page transitions but I have some trouble
(maybe it is not a big problem but I am still unable to solve)

OK, here is my plan:

My plan is, when a page loads, the  can slideDown so i did the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var velocity = ($('#main').height() / 500) * 1000;
    $('#main').css('display', 'none');
    $('#main').slideDown(velocity);
```

The velocity can make sure the speed of the slideDown can be calculated in pixels. So, longer page longer duration.

In the other hand, when I submit a form or click on a hyperlink, the page can slideUp then go to the page where it should be go to. Some of you may know the problem is that actually there is no time for the animation to do. Before the animation starts, the page has changed. So I coded event.preventtDefault() to stop it. Yeah, it stopped though, the event is actually removed so it didn't go anywhere. Anyway here is code:

```
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var velocity = ($('#main').height() / 500) * 1000;
        $('#main').slideUp(velocity);
        $('form').submit();
    });

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        if($('a').attr('href') != '') {
            var velocity = ($('#main').height() / 500) * 1000;
            $('#main').slideUp(velocity);
        }
        $(this).click();
    });
});
```

P.S.: Because of the CSS is brought by purecss.io so some links didn't have a href to go to (all the means, the slideUp works actually if the hyperlink does not have a href attrubute), so if the  does not have href don't make the page slideUp.

I know what is going wrong but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

---

HTML code using

```
<ul>
    <li><b><a>Menu</a></b></li>
    <li><a href="?action=index">Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="?action=announcement">Announcement</a></li>
    <li><a href="?action=sysmsg">System Message</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For the love of all that is **good** and **pure** in the world, please **don't** use page transitions.

Comment: you can go to the link address by using window.loaction.href = $(this).attr(href). Call this inside setTimeout(function(){});. Also, ($('#main').height() / 500) * 1000 is the same thing as *2. As James Hill said, I do not recommend this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here, thanks everyone who helped me, I appreciate it.
James may be right, I shouldn't use page transitions.
Simple is always the best. (Actually the effect not working properly in some situation)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').css('display', 'none');
    $('#main').slideDown($('#main').height());

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url !== '' && url.length > 0) {
            $('#main').slideUp($('#main').height(), function() {
                 window.location = url;
            });
        }
    });

    $(':submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#main').slideUp($('#main').height(), function() {
            $('form').trigger('submit');
        });
    });
});
```

For the guys who have a simple website, feel free to copy and use it. (or I would not post here)
For the guys who want to know the problem, well ...

1.
The links won't be opened in a new window whether i put target="_blank" or not.
Actually you can fix (browse another question in StackOverflow and you will find it)

2.
You will get stuck if you want to process form during submit. I have some JavaScript to check the input data of the form before submit it to the PHP page. It will engage the effect before the checkForm(). What I want to tell is if checkForm() return false, no document will be ready. All the means the page won't slide down again. i.e. YOU STUCKED! lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback from within the `slideUp` or `slideDown` function. This will be called **only once the animation has completed**. From within the callback you can use JavaScript to change the browser location (which I think is what you're looking for). Something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();

   if ( $(this).attr('href') !== '') {

       $('#main').slideUp( velocity, function() {

           var url = $(this).attr('href');

           window.location = url;

       });

   }

});
```

Comment: Thank you that made all the links works but the problem of the only <a> has not been solved. (I tried if url != '' then call this slideUp function but it slides up everytime)

Comment: In your example, you're testing `$('a').attr('href')` when you should be testing the clicked node by using `$(this)`-- see my example. This should fix the issue. Also, make sure that your empty links are actually empty. `console.log()` the link contents on click to make sure they are returning empty strings.